# vuejs 2 observation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, observable

I can't figure out why vuejs observation don't work on a very simple scenario. When the model "asker" is updated, computed props should automagically update value to 3. Why is this not working ? Fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/w1zz9cjs/3/

```
<div id="simulator">
<c-simulator-form v-bind:subject="asker"></c-simulator-form>
</div>

Vue.component('c-simulator-form', {
  props: ['subject'],
  template: '<div class="c-simulator-form">{{thesize}}</div>',
  computed: {
    thesize: function() {
      return _.size(this.subject);
    }
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#simulator',
  data: {
    asker: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    }
  }
});

vm.asker['c'] = 3;
```

Comment: "[Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)"

Comment: But it can with Arrays...

Comment: `vm.$set(vm.asker, 'c', 3)` or `Vue.set(vm.asker, 'c', 3)`

Comment: There are [caveats for Arrays](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this doesn't work is because Vue cannot detect property **addition** or **deletion** of any newly added properties for objects, i.e., the properties have to be already there for the object to be reactive.

Therefore, if you write

```
vm.asker['b'] = 4;
```

Vue will be able to detect the change (https://jsfiddle.net/n4qe3def/1/) while

```
vm.asker['c'] = 3;
```

doesn't work because `asker.c` is not reactive in Vue.

One way to fix this is like what [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) wrote in the comment:

`vm.$set(vm.asker, 'c', 3)` or `Vue.set(vm.asker, 'c', 3)`

But if you actually want to assign multiple new properties, the easier way is actually creating a new object for `asker` instead (https://jsfiddle.net/8618cx2h/2/):

```
vm.asker = Object.assign({}, vm.asker, { c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 })
```